# How to map a list of videogular2 videos

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, videogular

Based using ionic v.3 to build app. Here is the question:
I have a bulk list of video urls and each time fetch 10 to show on the page.

```
<vg-player>
  <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
  <video #media1 [vgMedia]="media1" src="{{videourl1}}"></video>
</vg-player>
<vg-player>
  <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
  <video #media2 [vgMedia]="media2" src="{{videourl2}}"></video>
</vg-player>
```

when in mapping, I can use [vgMedia]="{{video_id}}" to replace, but how about "#media1"?